# How to do I write signal-safe Python code?

Tags: python, signals

I'll start with an example code, that "should never" fail:

```
counter1 = 0
counter2 = 0


def increment():
    global counter1, counter2
    counter1 += 1
    counter2 += 1


while True:
    try:
        increment()
    except:
        pass
    assert counter1 == counter2
```

The counters represent an internal structure that should keep its integrity no matter what. By a quick look, the assertion will never be False, and the structure will be intact.

One small signal however, that occurs in the middle of the function (for example SIGINT or KeyboardInterrupt in Python) causes the internal structure to break. In real-world scenario it may cause memory corruption, deadlocks, and all other types of mayhem.

Is there any way to make this function signal safe? If any arbitrary code can run anywhere and cause it to malfunction, how can we program **library** code that is safe and secure?

Even if we attempt to guard it using `try...finally...`, we might still receive a signal at the `finally` and prevent it from running.

While the example is in Python, I believe this question applies to all programming languages as a whole.

EDIT:

Do keep in mind the counters are just an example. In my actual use case it's different Locks and `threading.Event`s. There's no real way (that I know of) to make the operation atomic.

Comment: Register a signal handler and handle the cleanup?

Comment: Won't really work. First of all, what would I register, a signal handler to all signals? Second of all, how will I handle correct cleanup if the signal handler throws an exception? What prevents a signal to pop during the cleanup?

Comment: Could you explain why you believe the example code can cause the issues you mention? Sure, lots of things can cause the assertion to fail, but I don't see how that can cause "memory corruption, deadlocks, and all other types of mayhem." A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be really helpful to be able to discuss possible problems and solutions.

Comment: The counters represent internal state. If let's say the counters are events, one will be triggered while the other won't. It can deadlock if you count on both of them triggering. If the counters signal indexes in 2 arrays, and don't advance together, it can cause data corruption. This is the simple and minimal example - How would I be able to guarantee the assertion to be true? Am I even able to guarantee it?

Comment: You can never get it fully atomic until you start using C extensions (I don't believe, anyway - the GIL does have its advantages!). My only (pure-Python) suggestion would be to create and join a thread that does the atomic work as SIGINT interrupts the main thread (you can call `join` a second time while the atomic work finishes). EDIT: I don't believe you can ever handle SIGKILL so there is nothing you can do in that situation

Comment: In my opinion you are approaching the problem from a wrong side. One should accept that signals and problems happen and focus on the internal data integrity with techniques like checkpointing and transactions.

Comment: `signal.signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` will truly ignore `SIGINT`, so that `KeyboardInterrupt` isn't raised in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Library code shouldn't ignore custom user-created signals.

Comment: @VPfB That's not always possible. In my case it can cause mismatching Locks and Events state which will potentially deadlock. (You usually don't expect random exceptions to be thrown between 2 consecutive lines of code)

Comment: @MinionJim Even C extensions won't guarantee safety. Syscall in a thread will get interrupted with InterruptedError, even when the signal is handled on the main thread.

Comment: @Bharel I'm not saying it should be ignored for the duration of the process. I see no problem with disabling it long enough to make sure both counters are incremented. Unless you mean that instead of ignoring it, the handler should ensure a particular block gets executed before addressing the signal, I agree, but doing that wouldn't fit in a comment :)

Comment: At least on UNIX, you can block delivery of signals using [signal.pthread_sigmask()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.pthread_sigmask). However if you're going to use this in library code it might not be the best idea to modify signals of the calling process.

Comment: @rocku indeed. And the current answer doesn't actually solve it. Not sure if it's even solvable.

Answer (score 10):

One solution to your example is to update the data [atomically](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe), if possible:

```
counters = [0, 0]

def increment():
    global counters

    # "complex" preparation. not atomic at all
    next0 = counters[0] + 1
    next1 = counters[1] + 1
    temp = [next0, next1]

    # actual atomic update
    counters = temp

try:
    while True:
        increment()
finally:
    assert counters[0] == counters[1]
```

No matter where the execution of the code stops, `counters` will always be in a consistent state, even without any cleanup.

Of course, this is a special case, which can't be always applied. A more general concept would be [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing) where multiple actions are bundled and either all get executed or none.
Errors during rollback/abort of a transaction can be still problematic, though.

There is a [transaction package](https://pypi.org/project/transaction/), but I did not look into that.

Comment: Is Python's lazy evaluation not a problem in this example or am I misunderstanding lazy evaluation?

Comment: @MinionJim What do you mean by "lazy"? This code works because you aren't updating the list referenced by `counters`, but *replacing* it with a brand new list.

Comment: @MinionJim this example only uses integers and lists. No lazy evaluation (e.g.  generator functions) here.

Comment: this will cause write after read issues in multi threaded situations

Answer (score 0):

best way is to used the techniques here. https://julien.danjou.info/atomic-lock-free-counters-in-python/
unfortunately other answers have some complex concurrency issues.